# Using Stack without a browser? List resolvers, search, etc.

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Is there a way to use Stack as a proper command line tool without constantly trying to navigate and search in a browser on [Stackage](http://stackage.org)?

I often want to search for a tool that I might want to install globally to see what version, if any, is offered.  Additionally, I sometimes want to see what resolver versions are available when considering upgrading a project.

As far as I can tell, this currently requires navigating to stackage.org, which is a very disruptive workflow.  Have I overlooked some kind of search command?

Comment: In my opinion, you've misidentified what your problem is. If you are working from the command line and opening a browser is too much of a workflow interruption, then get a command line browser (there are an absolute throng of these out there...). A web browser is (primarily) a tool to browse remote web servers. Any support stack has now or in the future for browsing stackage will be reinventing the wheel (in other words, stack is not a web browser, and so will never have the functionality of a web browser).

Comment: @user2407038 I strongly disagree with this.  A web browser is for viewing externally located documents, not for browsing general data.  Would you also suggest is not be possible to query package managers like apt without first loading a website?  Perhaps tools like curl shouldn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a soon-to-be-merged feature that will probably make it into the version after 1.6 https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/3252 , it lists snapshots.

One option to see the latest snapshots is to use what `stack build --resolver lts` or `--resolver nightly` uses.  You can also see what `stack init` chooses.

I don't think there are currently any direct ways to query what's in the snapshot from the CLI.  One option would be to do `stack build name-of-tool --dry-run`, and it will tell you what would be installed.

Generally, yes, I think stack could do a better job of letting you query info.  Some of it is tracked here - https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1614 .  Please consider discussing design of such features on the issue tracker, and possibly implementing the features.  That would be greatly appreciated and valuable to the community!

Also, you might like `stack hoogle`!  Very handy for getting offline info / without web browser, but requires that you build everything with docs enabled.

Comment: Thank you. This gives me a good overview of everything relevant.